# How much do the plates in Crossfit weigh?

Tags: bodybuilding

I've been a long time bodybuilder, but never tried Crossfit. I watched some videos of Crossfit athletes use large plates of the same size as the 45 pound plates I find in bodybuilding gyms. I am wondering if the Crossfit plates are also 45 lbs? From this knowledge, I would like to gauge my comparative strength as a bodybuilder.

[image]

Comment: All bumpers are the same circumference; you have to look at the color to determine the weight (and also figure out if it's lbs or kilos, which are used in formal Olympic competitions).

Comment: Also, given that it's a women in the photo she might be using a 15kilo bar instead of the standard 20(~45 lbs).

Comment: I had been wondering that too, but then started noticing more and more of that in pictures and some were marked at 25lbs. The bars still look like they're 45lbs, though.

Comment: @Greg, Green is either 10kg or 25lbs.  Yellow would be 15kg or 35 lbs.  Can't tell if they are using metric or imperial plates because the picture is too small.  The writing under the logo would say for sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plates in the picture are more than likely 25s. This is a photo from the 2010 CrossFit Games which, according to [this](http://board.crossfit.com/showthread.php?t=66212) thread, used [these plates](http://www.roguefitness.com/rogue-full-color-competition-bumpers.php).  They are known as "bumper plates" because they can be dropped on the ground. Watch Olympic weight lifting videos and you'll see them use similar large, colorful plates.

Comment: They are color coded: 10kg/25lb green.  15kg/35lb yellow.  20kg/45lb blue.  25kg/55lb red.  The only thing I can't tell from the OP's picture is whether they are pounds or kilograms.

Comment: Just to add, the color codes follows a color-scheme set by the IWF - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbell#Bumper_Plates

Comment: While CrossFit does use Olympic bars, they went backwards in time and decided to standardize in  "pounds" (which means the US market now pays more for Olympic-sized  plates since the market is now fragmented). CF colors "approximate" IWF coloring and weight. For example, IWF "green" is 10Kg (appx 22 pounds), but a Rogue "green" pounds plate is just 10 pounds. Although most Crossfit gyms have black bumper plates, with the largest plate typically 45 lbs (~20Kg).

Answer (score 1):

They weigh as much as they weigh. Because they're bumper plates, the plate diameter remains constant, making it tougher to tell how much is on the bar. Sometimes the plates will be color-coded for how much they weigh, but sometimes they aren't. They could weigh 45 pounds or one pound or 10 pounds.

Answer (score 0):

The plates in the pictures are competition bumpers from [Rogue Fitness](http://www.roguefitness.com/weightlifting-bars-plates/bumpers/competition-bumpers?bumpertype[0]=competition).

Women use [15kg bars](http://www.roguefitness.com/weightlifting-bars-plates/bars?cat3=weightliftingbarsplates_bars_womens15kgbars_id_4673) and Men use [20 kg](http://www.roguefitness.com/weightlifting-bars-plates/bars?cat3=weightliftingbarsplates_bars_mens20kgbars_id_4671) bars, and again, everything for the Games is supplied by Rogue.

If you want to compare yourself to Games athletes, here are the stats for the top 3 women and men from the 2014 Crossfit Games.

[Camille Leblanc Bazinet](http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/8404)
[Annie Thorisdottir](http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/18588)
[Julie Foucher](http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/46243)

[Rich Froning](http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/11435)
[Matt Fraser](http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/153604)
[Jason Khalipa](http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/12485)

EDIT : Ha! I just now realized this question was asked years ago. My bad.